# Guess the number of Morties

Tags: probability

Every time Morty dies Rick secretly replaces him with a clone. To keep track, Rick creates a folderfor each deceased Morty. Folders are numbered from 1 to whatever copy of Morty died last. One morning Morty discovers that, after going through his files Rick has accidentally left a folder with number 42 on his desk. After reading the file Morty realizes that he is a clone, and that there were at least 42 other Morties. However, he still does not know the truth about the total number of Morties that lived before him.

1. What is Morty’s best guess? By best guest I mean that the guess is an unbiased estimate of the total number of Morties. Assume that out of all folders, each had equal probability to be left on the desk by Rick.
2. Suppose that Morty finds two folders, 42 and 165. What is his best guess now? (For simplicity,you can consider appropriate continuous version of the problem).
3. Generalize for any number of folders Morty can discover on Rick’s desk.

Comment: This is best known as the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem . That page will likely be the best resource on the topic in the end!